# Guice, JerseyServletModule, missing dependency for method, REST service configuration

Tags: java, rest, servlets, guice

My Guice configuration looks something like:

```
public class SocialServiceGuiceConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {
   @Override
   protected Injector getInjector() {
       final Module [] modules = {
               new JerseyServletModule() {
                   @Override
                   protected void configureServlets() {
                       bind( GraphApi.class );

                       bind( SocialUncheckedExceptionMapper.class ).in( Singleton.class );
                       bind( SocialUnhandledExceptionMapper.class ).in( Singleton.class );

                       serve( "/*" ).with(
                           GuiceContainer.class );
                   }
               },
       };

       return Guice.createInjector( modules );
   } 
}
```

My API definition looks something like this:

```
@Path( "/{" + BUSINESS_CUSTOMER_PARAMETER + "}" )
public BusinessCustomerApi businessCustomerAndContext(
        @PathParam( BUSINESS_CUSTOMER_PARAMETER ) final BusinessCustomerPathParam businessCustomerPathParam,
        @QueryParam( LOCALE_PARAMETER ) final String locale) {
```

The exception I am getting in my logs:

```
INFO: Binding com.business.social.next.service.api.v1.GraphApi to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
Aug 13, 2012 9:20:05 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void com.business.social.next.service.api.v1.GraphApi.get(), MUST return a non-void type.
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public com.business.social.next.service.api.v1.BusinessCustomerApi com.business.social.next.service.api.v1.    GraphApi.graphRequestContext(com.business.social.next.graph.protocol.BusinessCustomer,java.lang.String) at parameter at index 0
Aug 13, 2012 9:20:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter Guice Filter
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
    at com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.servlet.GuiceContainer.initiate(GuiceContainer.java:121)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.init(ServletDefinition.java:117)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.init(ManagedServletPipeline.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.initPipeline(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:102)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.init(GuiceFilter.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3693)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4342)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1015)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1015)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Aug 13, 2012 9:20:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Aug 13, 2012 9:20:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Why is this happening?  Having a hard time finding information online and can't figure out what path to poke around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was not following the `@PathParam` type rules on the type `BusinessCustomerPathParam`.

The rules are outlined here: http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html

> The type of the annotated parameter, field or property must either:
>
> - Be `PathSegment`, the value will be the final segment of the matching part of the path. See `UriInfo` for a means of retrieving all request path segments.
> - Be `List<PathSegment>`, the value will be a list of `PathSegment` corresponding to the path segment(s) that matched the named template parameter. See `UriInfo` for a means of retrieving all request path segments.
> - Be a primitive type.
> - Have a constructor that accepts a single String argument.
> - Have a static method named `valueOf` or `fromString` that accepts a single String argument (see, for example, `Integer.valueOf(String)`).

I did not have a constructor that took a `String` or one of the `static` options.

Unfortunately the error message provided in the logs was not super useful.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same message while trying to bind interfaces that have injected parameters, however I had forgotten to add the `@Inject` annotation to my constructor.  Remember to check this as it had me banging my head against a wall for ages.